# Making a list of websites

Tags: urls

How do you add a website without giving an error?

```
 \begin{align*}
 1 &=\text{Google http://www.google.com}\\
 2 &= \text{MSN http://www.bing.com}\\
 \end{align*}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Do you want to do some kind of reference section?

Comment: Without your preamble it's hard to recreate your error. At a guess, are you missing the amsmath package?

Comment: Have amsmath package. If I leave out the url it works.  With it does not.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the behaviour you experience. Can you please update your post to make the problem reproducible? Please do so by supplying the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Answer (score 6):

since the purpose of this code is simply to list out the web sites, i have two suggestions:

- forget `align*`.  instead use the `enumerate` environment and enter the
  urls with `\verb+...+` as suggested by R. Schumacher.
- as previous, but instead of `\verb`, add `\usepackage{url}` and enter the
  site addresses as `\url{...}`.

`enumerate` will take care of numbering and alignment automatically.

you would really learn most of this by reading some introductory documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use inline verbatim (This does not wrap to next line) and puts it in courier not as a hyperlink.

```
 \verb+http://www.google.com+
```

Note: No extra spaces and the use of the + works only if there is not + in the http.  In that case you must use another non-alpha character(which is not in the http).

2) You can use the package hyperref and the manual is here http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/hyperref/manual.pdf  This sets up a hyperlink in your pdf.

3) You can use the package url and the manual is hee http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf  This sets up a hyperlink in your pdf.

4) IF you want to just include it as a text item in the document. You can replace each `\` with  `$\backslash$` and the `\\` with `$\backslash\backslash$`

Comment: I am just looking to print out the websites as text.  Without the sites the latex document works.

Comment: Then just use option 1 or 4 in the edited version.